# Is there any way to perform divisions on a generic type in .net (C++-CLI)?

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli

I'm trying to create a simple rolling mean implementation for generic numerical type but have hit a stumbling block:

```
generic<typename T>
public ref class RollingMean
{
protected:
    CircularBuffer<T> m_dataBuffer;
    T m_currentSum;

public:
    RollingMean(const int NumOfItems);

    T AddItem(const T NewItem);

    T CurrentMean()
    {
        return m_currentSum / static_cast<float>(m_dataBuffer.Length); // <--- gives me compiler error C2676
    }
};
```

This gives me a compiler error:

```
1>c:\projects\util\RollingMean.h(21): error C2676: binary '/' : 'T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>RollingMean.cpp(6): error C2955: 'MathHelpers::RollingMean' : use of class generic requires generic argument list
1>          c:\projects\util\RollingMean.h(9) : see declaration of 'MathHelpers::RollingMean'
```

Is there any way to limit the generic classes to those that are happy with numeric operations?

Comment: That's one of the famous limitations of reified generics vs templates.  Covered well in *many* questions here already.  There are no generic binary operators, you cannot divide an object by an object :)  And you cannot constrain the type argument to the value types that do support it, operator overloads are resolved at compile time.  Use method overloads or templates.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case but just couldn't find anything which explicitly says you can't do it.

Comment: Shame there's not an INumericType generic really.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this with generics. I suggest you follow the pattern set by the [Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class, which provides explicit overloads for each of the numeric types. Take [Enumerable.Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx), for example: It provides overloads for int, long, float, double, and Decimal, with no generic overload.